# How can i display the innerHTML when using an angularJS {{expression}}?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am displaying a message like this:

```
<td class="Msg">
  <div class="collapse">
    <h4 class="message">{{statement.Msg}}</h4>
  </div>
</td>
```

I have tried formatting in many ways but the message always appears like this:

```
a, b, c, d, e
```

But there should be a linebreak after each comma. When I look in FireBug, I see that the `innerHTML` is properly formatted.

How can I display the `innerHTML` of the `statement.Msg`?

**EDIT:** The message in the `innerHTML` is delimited by `\r\n`. That is how it's stored in the database and that's the `innerHTML` I see in FireBug, but it is not formatted that way on the page.

Comment: Like `white-space: pre;` on `.message`?

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce / <p ng-bind-html="myHTML"></p>

Comment: to clarify, the message in the innerHTML is delimited by \r\n. that is how its stored in the database and thats the innerHTML i see in FireBug, but it is not formatted that way on the page

Comment: you will have to run a msg.replace(/\r\n/, '<br />') if you want it to respect the line breaks.  you can create filter `break` that does that for you and then you can bind the html to `message|break`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I wrote in my comment: Add `white-space: pre;` on `.message` (Read [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) for all possible values available for the `white-space` style).

Example:

```js
angular.module('app', []).controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.statement = {Msg: "a,\r\nb,\r\nc,\r\nd"};
});
```

```css
.message { white-space: pre; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div class="collapse" ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
    <h4>{{statement.Msg}}</h4>
    <h4 class="message">{{statement.Msg}}</h4>
</div>
```

Note that the first `h4` element don't have `message` class so you won't get line breaks, while the second one do have this class.

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to use ngSanitize and ng-bind-html:

```
<h4 ng-bind-html="statement.Msg"></h4>
```

And in your AngularJS module:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngSanitize']);
```

For more information (including installation information) please read: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize

Comment: I think that since the user wrote: _"the message always appears like this: **a, b, c, d, e**"_ then it's just a css issue (As I wrote in my comment on the question), because I would expect they get something like `a,<br>b,<br>c,<br>d,<br>` using a regular expression, as demonstrated in the question

Comment: it's good to provide different options - it could be that your solution will do the job for him.